# React Routing doesn't work when I build the app - React JS, React Router DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have made a simple application with ReactJS `create-react-app` and used `react-router-dom`. The routing works perfectly when it is on the local server, but when I build the app, and I upload it to shared hosting, the routing doesn't work, and I get `404`. I don't know what is the problem.

I have followed many questions similar to mine StackOverflow, but none of them helped me, even I tried to use `HashRouting` instead of `BrowserRouting` but still the same problem.

**The ROOT Component**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Register from './Components/Auth/register.jsx';
import Login from './Components/Auth/login.jsx';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,  Route} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/app" exact component={App} />
        <Route path="/app/all" component={App} />
        <Route path="/app/history" component={App} />
        <Route path="/register"  component={Register}/>
        <Route path="/login"  component={Login}/>
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**Sub Component with Sub Children**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../SCSS/components.scss';
import ClockTable from '../Clock/Clock Components/clock-table'
import {Redirect, BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import History from './Clock Components/history'
import All from './Clock Components/all'
import { Cookies } from '../Globals.js'

export class Clock extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            authenticated : null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        // new Cookies().deleteAllCookies()
        if(new Cookies().getCookie('uid')){
            this.setState({
                authenticated : true,
            })
        } else{
            this.setState({
    authenticated : false
   })
        }
    }
    
    
    render() {
        if(this.state.authenticated === false){
            return <Redirect to='/login' />
        }
        return (
            <>
                <div className="container clock-sec">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div className="big-head">
                                CLOCK
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-3">
                            <div className="clock-left-table clock-sub-sec">
                                <ClockTable />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-9">
                            <Router>
                                <Route path="/app/all" exact component={All}/>
                                <Route path="/app/history" component={History}/>
                            </Router> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Clock
```

Comment: It's not a problem with `react-router-dom`. It's a server side issue. (*shameless plug*: If you are deploying on netlify, they provide a `_redirect` file which works for SPA routing. Pleae refer to [PAGE NOT FOUND ON NETLIFY WITH REACT ROUTER](https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2018/12/18/page-not-found-on-netlify-with-react-router/) for Netlify issue. Else, you'd have to find out how to redirect request for your web servers

Answer (score 0):

As @Sung M. Kim mentioned in his comment you need to set up your server to always serve the index.html file for all requests (besides if you have api calls).

The way to set this up is different with each server.